# NameError while running script from another script

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm trying to run scripts from given directory (including subdirs) and check the time of their execution.
When it comes to script where few functions are declared, I get `NameError: name %method_name% is not defined` for each function except the main function.

This is how I run the scripts:

```
def run_scripts(path):
    subdirs = os.listdir(path) 
    for subdir in subdirs:
        print('folder ' + subdir)
        files = os.listdir(path+'/'+subdir) 
        for file in files:
            print(os.path.dirname(file))
            if file.endswith('py'): 
                print('script \"' + os.path.basename(file) + '\"')
                print("output ", end='')
                start_time = time.time()
                exec(open(path+'/'+subdir+'/'+file, encoding='utf-8').read())
                print("time: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And this is part of the executable script which provokes NameError:

```
filename = 'wiki.txt'

def letters_only(s):
    s = s.strip()
    for c in s:
        if not ((c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') or (c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z') or c == ' '):
            s = s.replace(c, '')
    return s 

def count_words(s):
    result = {}
    words = s.split()
    for w in words:
        if w in result.keys():
            result[w] += 1
        else:
            result[w] = 1
    return result

# other methods...

# main function
def wiki_function():
    f = open('wiki.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    data = f.readlines() 
    for line in data:
        print(line)
    non_empty = []
    for line in data:
        if (line != '') and (line != '\n'):
            non_empty.append(letters_only(line)) # NameError
    text = ' '.join(non_empty)
    word_freq = count_words(text) # NameError
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wiki_function()
```

What should I do to make the functions work?

Comment: Are `count_words` and `letters_only` defined inside a class?

Comment: Nope. There are no any classes

Comment: Please provide a _runnable_ [mre].

Comment: `exec(open(path+'/'+subdir+'/'+file, encoding='utf-8').read())` what if you replace this with `os.system("python3 filename.py")`?

Comment: With `os.system("python3 filename.py")` it works! Thanks